# On the formal definition of vectors?

Tags: reference-request, vectors, analytic-geometry

If one wishes to formalize the notion of vectors in space it is necessary to introduce an equivalence relation in the three dimensional space $\mathbb E^3$ of euclidean geometry which identifies oriented line segments which have the same length (and more).

Since one mentions ``length'' in that equivalence relation, it is implicit we are using some fixed metric in $\mathbb E^3$, right? I'm asking because all the books I've seen on analytic geometry does not mention this. So, is the metric really there or is there some geometric trick to avoid talking about it?

Is there any reference which discuss this kind of formalism?

Thanks.

P.s.: I see $\mathbb E^3$ as an abstract set from which one distinguishes the subsets whose elements are lines and whose elements are planes. So, I initially don't have a coordinate system, for instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the notion of vectors on space"?

Comment: Formally, you don't need any geometrical object to define vectors. A vector space is just an abelian group on whic a field acts. -- But starting from Euclidean geometry, we can define a vector as an equivalence class ofordered pairs of points, where two pairs are equivalent if they form a parallelogram. This gives us the abelian group, and quickly the structure of a $\Bbb Q$-vector space. We might not get all the way to an $\Bbb R$-vector space, though, but certainly to a pythagorean field (closure of $\Bbb Q$ under square root)

Comment: And of course your "space" as an affine copy of the 3-dimensional (real) vector space, so you get the "difference" of any two points, $\overrightarrow{PQ}$, is a vector for free.  There are no identifications of oriented line segments etc., needed here.

Comment: @user10354138 I meant "vectors in space" as directed line segments, which you study in analytical geometry.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What if $(A, B)$ and $(C, D)$ are collinear? They still can define the same vector but they don't define a parallelogram.

Comment: @user10354138 I know the affine space approach, but it is not the natural development of the theory, at least from my standpoint. As I see, it is natural to define "free vectors" and introduce algebraic operations which have the properties of a vector space and then to abstract it.

Comment: Furtheremore, if we don't use a metric, how could we define multiplication by scalars using only geometry?